# WPF get a command line argument into a viewmodel from mainwindow

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm trying to learn WPF and have a case where i have to pass a command line argument to a viewmodel. i was able to get the parameter from app.xaml and pass to MainWindow, but how do i get this parameter from mainwindow to the viewmodel. also if i add a constructor to the view model, then i cant declare it in in the datacontent in the xaml view  - if i do it in the codebehind, i dont get the intellisense, which i another problem.

If you could point me to a simple example or even the pattern if need to do this type of thing that would be great.

View model

```
    public class RepoViewModel
    {
        private VcsRepo repo;
        public RepoViewModel()
        {
            // this is where i need that parameter from mainwindow
            this.repo = new VcsRepo(new Repository([my parameter]));
        }
        public VcsRepo Repo
        {
            get { return repo; }
            set { repo = value; }
        }
    }
```

The view

```
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:RepoViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Repo.Files}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest thing to do is use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs

Answer (score -1):

This document provide command line argument.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/application-management-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#processing-command-line-arguments

1. Change `StartUpUri` to `Startup` in `App.xaml`.

```xml
<Application ..."
             Startup="App_OnStartup">
```

2. Create `MainWindow` instance, include `e.Args`(in `StartupEventArgs`).

```cs
private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
   new MainWindow(e.Args).Show();
}
```

3. Pass arguments from `MainWindow` to ViewModel.

```cs
public MainWindow(string[] eArgs)
{
   InitializeComponent();

   DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(eArgs);
}
```

But i don't recommend this, how about dependency injection pattern? Like `Prism` etc..

Comment: i actually did exactly what you said, but where i'm still stuck is getting that argument from the mainwindow into another view model that requires it as a parameter to contruct the viewmodel class. I'm guessing that's were dependency injection comes in.